# Embedded Linux install ALSA and play audio `aplay` problem

Tags: audio, embedded-linux, alsa

I work on embedded linux on buildroot. I struggle for play audio. I opened `alsa-lib`,`alsa-utils`,`aplay`. Buildroot use `sun4i-codec` audio codec. I use `modprobe=sun4i-codec` and installed it. `lsmod` command return installed drivers.

aplay -l command returned:

```
card 0: sun4icodec[sun4i-codec], device 0: CDC PCM Codec-0 [ ]   
 Subdevices:1/1          
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

aplay -L command returned:

```
null   
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)   
default:CARD=sun4icodec   
sun4i-codec,   
Default-Audio-Device   
sysdefault:CARD=sun4icodec  
sun4i-codec   
>Default Audio Codec
```

I tried different combination:
1- I use `speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6 -twav` command. Result:`Playback open error:-2,No such file or directory`
2- I use `aplay sounfile.wav` and `aplay -D "default:CARD=name_of_card" /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Side_Left.wav` command. Result:`aplay:pcm_write:2053: write error: Input/output error`
3- I tried play audio and test audio with gsreamer-1.0 but I can't hear any sound.

**Note:** Refer to this page myself:http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=ALSA_Installation but I use Allwinner A13 microprocess.

What's wrong ? Where is the problem ?

Comment: Are you using device tree for i2s configuration respective to your CODECs?

Comment: No. I began use different kernel version. I will write result when I try this.